# Make NSCollectionLayoutItem heights as tall as the NSCollectionLayoutGroup when using estimated heights in a UICollectionViewLayout grid

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I have a `UICollectionViewLayout` grid with three columns. Each item in the column has a cell full of text. I would like all the columns to be the same height as the tallest item in the group. Using `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` I'm having a hard time getting the desired results.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? All the code is below. The `createLayout` function is the most relevant. Please note I am using [LoremSwiftum](https://github.com/lukaskubanek/LoremSwiftum.git) to generate the random text.

**Current behavior**
[image]

**Expected behavior:**

I was able to mock this expected behavior by changing the `NSCollectionLayoutSize` to be an absolute value of 500. This is *not* what I want. Each cell should estimate its size, and use the largest value of the group.

```
let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                      heightDimension: .absolute(500))
let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        
let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                       heightDimension: .absolute(500))
```

[image]

**Entire Code:**

```
import UIKit
import LoremSwiftum


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    enum Section {
        case main
    }
    
    var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Int>! = nil
    var collectionView: UICollectionView! = nil
    let sectionBackgroundDecorationElementKind = "section-background-element-kind"
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "Two-Column Grid"
        configureHierarchy()
        configureDataSource()
    }
    
    /// - Tag: TwoColumn
    func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        let spacing = CGFloat(10)

        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                              heightDimension: .estimated(44))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                               heightDimension: .estimated(44))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 3)
        group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(spacing)
        
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.interGroupSpacing = spacing
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 10)

        
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
        return layout
    }
    
    func configureHierarchy() {
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: createLayout())
        collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }
    
    func configureDataSource() {
        let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<TextCell, Int> { (cell, indexPath, identifier) in
            // Populate the cell with our item description.
            cell.label.text = Lorem.sentences(Bool.random() ? 1 : 3)
        }
        
        dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Int>(collectionView: collectionView) {
            (collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath, identifier: Int) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
            // Return the cell.
            return collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: cellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: identifier)
        }
        
        // initial data
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Int>()
        snapshot.appendSections([.main])
        snapshot.appendItems(Array(0..<94))
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
    }
}




class TextCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let label = UILabel()
    let bottomLabel = UILabel()
    let container = UIView()
    static let reuseIdentifier = "text-cell-reuse-identifier"
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("not implemented")
    }
    

    func configure() {
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
        label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1)
        label.backgroundColor = .systemPurple
        label.textColor = .white

        
        bottomLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        bottomLabel.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
        bottomLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1)
        bottomLabel.text = "Bottom of cell"
        bottomLabel.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        bottomLabel.textColor = .white
        
        
        let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [label, bottomLabel])
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.distribution = .equalSpacing
        stack.spacing = 20
        contentView.addSubview(stack)

        backgroundColor = .systemBlue.withAlphaComponent(0.75)

        let inset = CGFloat(10)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: inset),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -inset),
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: inset),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -inset),
        ])
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Got any solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For WWDC23, Apple update UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout to have this ability. Just use uniformAcrossSiblings(estimate:) as the height dimension. You can read more about it in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nscollectionlayoutdimension/4173072-uniformacrosssiblings).

Answer (score 6):

I ended up having to create a `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` subclass, but the solution works really well.

Using the new subclass, keep a weak reference to the layout in your cell so you can use it in `preferredLayoutAttributesFitting`.

```swift
class EqualHeightsUICollectionViewCompositionalLayout: UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
    private var heights = [Int: [IndexPath: CGFloat]]()
    private var largests = [Int: CGFloat]()
    private let columns: Int

    init(section: NSCollectionLayoutSection, columns: Int) {
        self.columns = columns
        super.init(section: section)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
        
        if #unavailable(iOS 15) {
            if let attributes = attributes {
                for attribute in attributes {
                    updateLayoutAttributesHeight(layoutAttributes: attribute)
                }
            }
        }
        
        return attributes
    }
    
    override func invalidateLayout() {
        super.invalidateLayout()

        heights.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
        largests.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
    }
    
    func updateLayoutAttributesHeight(layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
        let height = layoutAttributes.frame.height
        let indexPath = layoutAttributes.indexPath
        let row = indexPath.item / columns

        heights[row]?[indexPath] = height
        
        largests[row] = max(largests[row] ?? 0, height)
        
        let size = CGSize(width: layoutAttributes.frame.width,
                          height: largests[row] ?? 0)
        layoutAttributes.frame = .init(origin: layoutAttributes.frame.origin, size: size)
    }
}
```

```swift
class TextCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let label = UILabel()
    weak var layout: EqualHeightsUICollectionViewCompositionalLayout?

    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .systemBlue.withAlphaComponent(0.75)
        configure()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("not implemented")
    }

    override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
        let attribute = super.preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(layoutAttributes)
        layout?.updateLayoutAttributesHeight(layoutAttributes: attribute)
        return attribute
    }
    
    private func configure() {
        let bottomLabel = UILabel()
        
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1)
        label.backgroundColor = .systemPurple
        label.textColor = .white
        label.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        
        bottomLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        bottomLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1)
        bottomLabel.text = "Bottom of cell"
        bottomLabel.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        bottomLabel.textColor = .white
        bottomLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
        
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [label, bottomLabel])
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 20

        contentView.addSubview(stackView)
        
        let padding: CGFloat = 15
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: padding),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -padding),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: padding),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
        ])
    }
}
```

Comment: good solution,  I'am facing some issue on func invalidateLayout()

Comment: What kind of issue?

Comment: I'am using multi section and so while calling 'heights.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true), largests.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)' inside 'invalidateLayout()' array cleared , is it necessary to call 'heights.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true), largests.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)' inside 'invalidateLayout()' ?

Comment: Anytime the layout is invalidated, both dictionaries must be cleared. So yes, it is necessary to call it in invalidateLayout()

Comment: thanks for sharing @RichardWitherspoon!

Comment: Note if you can't use uniformAcrossSiblings, you _must_ override `-layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:` as well as `-layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` so UICollectionView sees the same attributes from both methods.

Comment: Hi @RichardWitherspoon can you provide the full code for this case ? because in my collection cell class the layout is getting as nil. where do we need to call the EqualHeightsUICollectionViewCompositionalLayout class ? and where to initialize ?

Comment: @sarosar EqualHeightsUICollectionViewCompositionalLayout is the layout that you supply to your collection view. You can find the code [here](https://github.com/Rspoon3/UIKitTesting/tree/3ed486ed629df38217f799a83d69443350f3136a).